# Why is there always a symmetry in my perlin noise function in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I always have some sort of wierd symmetry in my perlin noise. This always happens and I have tried doing many solutiond

I tried offsetting my code a little, but no matter what I would do, I would always get a wierd form of symetry.

```
        int verticesx = (cubeAmountX) + 1;
        int verticesy = (cubeAmountY) + 1;
        for(float x = ((chunkX) * (cubeAmountX/3)); x < verticesx + ((chunkX) * (cubeAmountX/3)); x++){
            for(float y = ((chunkY) * (cubeAmountY/3)); y < verticesy + ((chunkY)* (cubeAmountY/3)); y++){
                float perlinNoiseResult = Mathf.PerlinNoise((x + 0.1f) / 100 * scale + 132765, (y + 0.2f) / 100 * scale + 38789);
                perlinNoiseResult *= (Mathf.PerlinNoise((x + 0.3f) / 100 * scale * (x + 0.4f) / 100 * scale + 132765, (y + 0.5f) / 100 * scale * (y + 0.6f) / 100 * scale + 38789)) / 5 + 1;
                float biomeDecider = (Mathf.PerlinNoise(Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Abs(x + 0.7f) / 100 * scale) + 132765, Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Abs(y + 0.8f) / 100 * scale) + 38789));
                biomeDecider = 1/(1+Mathf.Pow(2,(-16*(biomeDecider - 0.5f))));
                perlinNoiseResult *= biomeDecider + 0.1f;
                
                vertices.Add(new Vector3(x * lengthBetweenVertices, perlinNoiseResult * maxheight - 10, y * lengthBetweenVertices));
                uv.Add(new Vector2(x/verticesx,y/verticesy));
                for(int ix = 0;ix < detail * lengthBetweenVertices;ix++){
                    for(int iy = 0; iy < detail * lengthBetweenVertices;iy++){
                        Color color = CalculateColor(Mathf.PerlinNoise((x + ix/detail/lengthBetweenVertices)/ 100 * scale, (y + iy/detail/lengthBetweenVertices) / 100 * scale) * biomeDecider * maxheight - 10, maxheight);
                        texture.SetPixel((int)x * (int)detail * (int)lengthBetweenVertices + ix,(int)y * (int)detail * (int)lengthBetweenVertices + iy,color);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: My "geometry" is happiest when I stick with doubles. I notice that in some case; you are dividing ints by ints, giving other ints; resulting in truncation. Not sure if that's what you want; but that will cause (a type of) "symmetry" due to lost values.

Comment: That code could probably be significantly more readable by shortening line lengths, and using vector operations where appropriate. You might also consider posting a picture of your result to show what you are talking about.

Comment: A general More performance related side note: Don't use `SetPixel` in a loop! Rather use `SetPixels` and modify an array instead ... And yeah break up those long lines, use constants instead of magic numbers, reuse the same value in multiple places .. it's extremely hard to follow the thread right now

Comment: At a couple of places you also take the `Mathf.Abs` which would of course introduce symmetry potential .. might want to multiply be the `Mathf.Sign` again